# Creating text elements in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is dynamically created in my JS.  Everything works except the line breaks.  Am I appending them incorrectly?

```
var reminderDiv = document.getElementById('reminderDiv');

var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
var reminderName = document.createTextNode(item.name);
h2.appendChild(reminderName);

var reminderDetails = document.createElement('p');
var br = document.createElement('br');
var reminderOccasion = document.createTextNode('Occasion: ' + item.occasion);    
var reminderLastGift = document.createTextNode('Last Gift:' + item.lastgift);   
var reminderPrefGift = document.createTextNode('Preferred Gift:' + item.prefgift);
reminderDetails.appendChild(reminderOccasion);
reminderDetails.appendChild(br);
reminderDetails.appendChild(reminderLastGift);
reminderDetails.appendChild(br);
reminderDetails.appendChild(reminderPrefGift);
```

Comment: You only have a single BR element here. appendChild doesn’t clone nodes, it removes the node from its current document position first.

Answer (score 5):

> Everything works except the line breaks

Line break: Singular.

You only create one. You then append it twice. So it gets appended after `reminderOccasion` and then again after `reminderLastGift` (which removes it from its previous position).

Comment: Thanks.  That makes total sense.  If I want multiple breaks, is there a cleaner way to do it than 3 variables each creating a line break?

Comment: Reuse the same variable (but assign it a new value!) or don't use a variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you're inserting the same element over and over again. 
You should create new `<br>` tag each time when you will append it.